# Count occurence of occurence in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count a occurence of a occurence in a dataframe, basically what I am doing right now:

```
dfhelp = df.groupby('Art')['Number'].count().reset_index()
dfhelp = dfhelp.groupby('Number')['Art'].count().reset_index()
dfhelp.head(2)
Number  Art
0   1   4
1   2   118855
```

which gives me the right output, but how can I run this in a simplier way?

In the first step I count the number how many rows a "Art" has, and in the second step I count how often this occurences appears.

The original dataframe looks like this:

```
Art Number
A    1001
A    20101
A    11
B     2
B     3
C     2
C     2
```

would lead to:

```
Number  Art
3        1
2        2
```

Note the first groupby `dfhelp = df.groupby('Art')['Number'].count().reset_index()`leads to:

```
Art Number
A    3
B    2
C    2
```

Comment: The question is not very clear, but is this what you are looking for? `df.groupby(['Art', 'Number']).size().reset_index()`

Comment: I try to verify it in my edit, and its not the solution you provide, sorry

Comment: Can you please elaborate the exact problem? It is unclear as to what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: I tried to clarify it once more

Comment: I don't think it can be shorter. You can do a one-liner like `df.assign(Num=df.groupby('Art')['Number'].transform("size")).groupby("Num")["Art"].nunique()` but its still two `groupby` required.